# creating file copies using fileoutputstream

Tags: java, fileinputstream

i'm trying to write a simple program to copy a file and make several copies as specified by the user. the files are being created but fout.write(i) doesn't seem to be writing the data into the copies

```
import java.io.*;

public class createCopies {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i;
    
    if (args.length != 2) {
        
        System.out.println("enter file to copy and number of copies");
    }

    try (FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(args[0])) {
        FileOutputStream fout = null;

        try {
            do{
                i = fin.read();
                System.out.println(i);
                int  b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
                for(int k= 0; k <= b; k++){
                    String fname = k+"_"+args[0];
                    fout = new FileOutputStream(fname);
                    if(i != -1) fout.write(i);
                }
            }while (i != -1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if (fout != null) fout.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html)

From the documentation you can see that you can copy file from to a destination:

```
Files.copy(source, destination, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

To copy multiple Files just use some sort of List:

```
List<File> files = new ArrayList();
files.add(foundFile);
```

And then with for-each loop just copy them wherever you want :)